# ASP.NET Web Application Deployment using TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I am trying to find out how other companies similiar to mine are deploying their web applications into production.

We have the traditional 3 environment setup (Dev, Stage, Prod)
Once the application has been tested in Stage, we XCopy the files to Production, setup IIS and it is deployed.

We recently purchased TFS 2010 and we basically use it the same way we used VSS in the past, just to store source code.

I am trying to find the most efficient way of doing deployments of our web applications. Any suggestions?

Comment: How often are you doing deployments? Like are you doing nightly builds? If you're doing frequent builds and automatic deployments but don't want to use TFS "add-ons", setup Auto Builds with TFS. You'll see it in your Team Project nodes, "Builds". You can setup automatic builds and triggers on when you'll do the build. You can setup a "drop" folder so your 3 environments will pick them up. But if you don't mind using TFS "add-ons" (as I like to call them), use TFS Deployer as what has been suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use Tfs Deployer (http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/) along side a custom powershell script to do the actual deployment.  Then a slight tweak to the build template to set an initial build quality.

It means we can push the exact same build to any (existing) environment and it's easy enough that non technical people can do it.  It's also a nice extension point where I can integrate other things (automated tests/emails) which can also feed back into the system and kick off deployment to the next stage.

Comment: Thanks! I going to look into TFSDeployer today.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use web deploy or use an installer package e.g. WiX. We usually use an installer package, as we typically have a lot of environment dependent konfiguration. With a single installer package you install and test the same set of binaries throughout your deployment pipeline, but with different configurations (e.g. web.config) specified when installing. You can remote install from msbuild using psexec.